# istream_iterator to initialize vector

Tags: c++, vector, istream-iterator

I'm trying to read from a ifstream **fin** and put it into a vector **vec1** using istream_iterators. I've seen these things all over the place:

```
vector<int> vec1((istream_iterator<int>(fin)),istream_iterator<int>);
```

I want to keep the istream_iterators for later use, so I thought "This should work":

```
istream_iterator<int> iit(fin);
istream_iterator<int> eos;
vector<int> vec1(iit,eos);
```

... It doesn't work =( my vector is completly empty. (the file i read from is a txt-file with nothing but digits).

**EDIT:** The txt looks as follows:

```
06351784798452318596415234561
6641321856006
```

Comment: Is there spaces between the digits? If there is not, or if the first sequence of digits before the first whitespace character, then it may be that the digits is greater than the maximum integer value and it will not be read.

Comment: Can you provide a complete, minimal example along with the exact input? See http://SSCCE.ORG for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment, the first sequence of digits is greater than the maximum value for an `int` so the input operation will fail resulting in the `vector` remaining empty.

You can obtain the maximum values for `int`, etc using the [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) template:

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried separating the digits with a whitespace and now it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

As an intermediate step you might want to try iterating over the sequence immediately to see if there is something (probably not):

```
while (iit != eos) {
    std::cout << *iit++ << '\n';
}
```

If this doesn't print anything check that your stream is in good shape initially:

```
if (!fin) {
    std::cout << "file not opened!\n";
}
```

If the stream only contaibs digits and no spaces it probably overflows and reading an `int` just fails as a result.

Comment: I tried iterating over the sequence, but it was empty. And I already have a file-controll.